# How do I line up villages next to each other?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build a Iron Golem farm, and actually understand the logic behind it. To make it efficient, I've seen setups with multiple villages next to each other to increase the spawn rate, but I don't know how to do that.

I know that villages are defined by doors with a block above them (to simulate a roof I guess), but how do I line up separate villages next to each other? I guess it's a certain order/pattern to placing/breaking doors, but that's just my guess.

If it matters, I'm using snapshot 14W21B.

Comment: Ahh okay, cheers

Comment: I'm sloppy today, deleted my comment. I removed the snapshot 14W21B from the title because there should be a general answer that works for any recent version of Minecraft. Otherwise, were you able to do this in any other version of Minecraft and found that your version had specific problems? Or were you just stating your current version for information?

Comment: I was stating it just to say, and also I heard that in 1.8 they were changing villages